# If one value is a string, then entire ID is filtered out in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have day as so:

```
ID   status
001       x
001       x
002       y
002    test
002       y
003    test 
003       x
004       x
```

All I want to do in Snowflake is remove any ID's which have even one occurrence of `test`. In doing so I seek the final result as:

```
ID   status
001       x
001       x
004       x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table
where ID not in (select ID from table where status = 'test')
```

or using window functions:

```
select * from ( 
    select * , max(case when status ='test' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ID) flag
) t where t.flag = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`

```
select  
    id, 
    status
from myTable m1
where not exists (
  select id 
  from myTable m2
  where m1.id = m2.id
  and status = 'test'
)
```

output:

```
*--------------*
| id    status |
*--------------*
| 001    x     |
| 001    x     |
| 004    x     |
*--------------*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from t
where sum(case when status = 'test' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can use this:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3319347b1a37e077775a01d42e7d1aa

Although it is a long solution here you can use list_agg() to solve this. Please note I have used group_concat but in snowflake, the equivalent is list_agg()

```
with all_data as (

select * from data
),

list_concat as (
select 
id,
group_concat(status) as list_of_status
from all_data
group by 1

),

join_data as (

select 

list_concat.id,
all_data.status,
list_concat.list_of_status


from list_concat
left join all_data
on all_data.id = list_concat.id

)

select * from join_data
where list_of_status NOT LIKE '%test%'
```